# .Net Core Reset Password Token and Identityserver 4 token invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

My applications and APIs are protected using IdentityServer 4.

I have a centralized API for user management (registering new users, updating, deleting and resetting passwords). The token generated by this api will be used by identityserver to reset the user's password.

*Problem is I always get invalid token error.* I know this has nothing to do with url encoding because forgotten password is handled by identity server and the token generated by identity server works fine. The problem is when a token is generated by different api (even on a single machine).

I looked into creating a common data protection provider but I'm unclear how this is done. **Basically, how can I have reset password token created by one api accepted by another?**

I'm using Asp Identity's usermanager to generate the reset password token:

```
var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(appUser);
```

This is how my IdentityServer is setup to use Asp Identity:

```
services
    .AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
            options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
            options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = new System.TimeSpan(12, 0, 0);
            options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = int.Parse(Configuration["MaxFailedAttempts"]);
        })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

...

var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
                options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
                options.Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration = true;
            })
            .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
            .AddConfigurationStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
                    b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                    sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                    options.DefaultSchema = Globals.SCHEMA_IDS;
                })
            // this adds the operational data from DB (codes, tokens, consents)
            .AddOperationalStore(options =>
                {
                    options.ConfigureDbContext = b =>
                    b.UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                    sql => sql.MigrationsAssembly(migrationsAssembly));

                    options.DefaultSchema = Globals.SCHEMA_IDS;
                    // this enables automatic token cleanup. this is optional.
                    options.EnableTokenCleanup = true;
                    options.TokenCleanupInterval = 30;
                })
            .AddProfileService<CustomProfileService>()
            .AddSigninCredentialFromConfig(Configuration.GetSection("SigninKeyCredentials"), Logger);
```

and this is how my UserManagement Api is setup to use Asp Identity:

```
services.AddTransient<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, ApplicationDbContext>>();
services.AddTransient<IRoleStore<IdentityRole>, RoleStore<IdentityRole, ApplicationDbContext>>();
services.AddTransient<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>, PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>>();
services.AddTransient<ILookupNormalizer, UpperInvariantLookupNormalizer>();
services.AddTransient<IdentityErrorDescriber>();

var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(typeof(ApplicationUser), typeof(IdentityRole), services);
identityBuilder.AddTokenProvider("Default", typeof(DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>));
services.AddTransient<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had to move on to other issues and just now getting back to this. I ended up solving this by ensuring that all my APIs and IdentityServer instance was configured to use ASP.NET Core Data Protection. I'm using redis as my distributed caching system and so just had to configure each of my api and identityserver and everything is now using the same keys when generating tokens. Below is what I use in each startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  ...            
            services.AddSession();
            services.Configure<RedisConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("redis"));
            services.AddDistributedRedisCache(options =>
            {
                options.Configuration = Configuration.GetValue<string>("redis:host");
            });
            var redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(Configuration.GetValue<string>("redis:host"));
            services.AddDataProtection()
                .PersistKeysToRedis(redis, "DataProtection-Keys")
                .SetApplicationName(<application name>);
            services.AddTransient<ICacheService, CacheService>();
...
}
```

and then don't forget to use the session (in APIs):

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            ...
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSession();
            ...
        }
```

use the session (in IdentityServer):

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            ...
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseSession();
            ...
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is a 2 months old question you already soled it I guess. My suggestion would be: take a look at the life span of your token. And set it in your startup.cs like this:

```
services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(options =>
{
  options.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(tokenlifespan); 
});
```

Hope this will help you out!

Comment: Thanks for the response. This happened to be an issue with the token generation between APIs and IdentityServer I had to configure ASP.NET Core Data Protection (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same "invalid token" issue with IdentityServer4 on ASP.NET Core 3.1.

An answer of [Prathamesh Shende on learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/934966/invalid-token-on-password-reset-asp-net-core-ident#answer-935912) solved it for me:

In the ResetPassword action, the code first needed to be decoded before being passed on to the _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync method. Like so:

```
var decodedCode = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(model.Code));
```