# When I create Reset Password Token with multi instance IdentityServer getting Invalid Token Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

When I create Reset Password Token IdentityServer getting Invalid Token Error. Identity Server running 2 instances. If Reset Password Token is created in different instances then the error I get is Invalid Token

```
            .AddSigningCredential(new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(rsa.GetKey(rsaKeyJson), RsaSigningAlgorithm.RS512.ToString()));
```

I wrote **rsaKeyJson** to database so every instances uses the same rsaKey.

I am not sure my problem is  with SigninCredentialsKey.

Because Authorize Token is working multiple instances.

But Reset Password Token is not working.

Answer (score 1):

When you have multiple instances of IdentityServer, then you must make sure they  both have the same Data Protection API signing key. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0) for details.

Also, you must make sure both instances uses the same private token signing key. This you can check by making sure the key is the same here on both instances:

https://identityserver.myserver.com/.well-known/openid-configuration/jwkson

See this Stackoverflow question:

- [.Net Core Reset Password Token and Identityserver 4 token invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51583859/net-core-reset-password-token-and-identityserver-4-token-invalid)

Comment: can u check new version of question?

Comment: Have you also configured the data protection API properly? See my blog post about it here https://www.edument.se/post/storing-the-asp-net-core-data-protection-key-ring-in-azure-key-vault?lang=en

Comment: Do the two instances share the same database where the issued tokens are stored?

Comment: I guess the issued tokens are not stored. I think GenerateResetPasswordToken method is stored the tokens in-memory. Because there is no token in Database.

Comment: is this problem about with DataProtectionApi

Comment: I stored the rsakey. All instances using the same rsakey that I stored to Database

Comment: See my updated answer, with a link to another Stack question.  AddSigningCredential is all about how the tokens are signed. But The Data Protection is about how the session cookies generated by each ASP.NET instance is created, important information is stored in the cookies and to allow the other instance to read the cookie, then they need to both to use the same data protection keys.  This is separate from the signing token.